# Royalslider link two galleries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Since, I didn't find anything here or on google, I was wondering if there is a way to link two galleries together in royalslider? 
Meaning, instead of looping or stopping at the last images of gallery-1, royalslider is supposed to simply go on with images of gallery-2.

I tried to come up with a workaround but failed so far to have anything useful yet ...

Here is the link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv6Ljmaf/1/) `enter code here`

Comment: Could you provide us some [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and code?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/zv6Ljmaf/1/